# TableView Controller not sending variable to details controller

Tags: swift3

I have researched this issue and I'm almost certain my code is correct, but clearly there is something wrong. I have two controllers. One has a TableView and the other is a view controller with a label. I want the value of the cell text label in the tableview cell selected by the user to be sent to the second view controller. Pretty simple. Here are my controllers:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class FavoritesViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var selectedFavorite = ""

var specifiedFavorite:String!

let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

var passages = [NSManagedObject]()

//This code creates the number of cells equal the number of items in the object
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return passages.count

}


// The code below displays the passage reference as the cell title
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // This creates the cell for the table. The dequeueReusableCell option ensures the table is scrollable
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    // this creates a variable for the record defined at the index that is numbered by the indexPath.row.
    let favorite = passages[indexPath.row]
    // We then find the value of the key we want to set for the cell label value
    cell.textLabel!.text = favorite.value(forKey: "reference") as? String

    return cell

}


// This code detects the cell selected and captures a variable that is passed in the segue
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let selectedCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as UITableViewCell!

    selectedFavorite = (selectedCell?.textLabel?.text)!

    print("The text in the selected cell is \(selectedFavorite)")

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "toFavoritesDetailsViewController", sender: nil)

    print("Segue performed")

}

//This code is the segue that passes the variable values to the next view
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toFavoritesDetailsViewController" {

        let favoritesDetailsViewController = segue.destination as! FavoritesDetailsViewController

        favoritesDetailsViewController.specifiedFavorite = selectedFavorite

        print("The variable for selectedFavorite prior to segue is: \(selectedFavorite)")

        print("The variable for favoritesDetailsViewController.specifiedFavorite prior to segue is: \(favoritesDetailsViewController.specifiedFavorite)")

    }
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

//This code loads the Core Data Entity into the view
// this is working as evidenced by the tableview being populated with data
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName:"Passages")
    //
    do {
        let results = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
        passages = results as! [NSManagedObject]
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch \(error)")
    }
  }

}
```

Here is the code for my second controller called FavoritesDetailsViewController:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class FavoritesDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var referenceLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var passageText: UITextView!

var specifiedFavorite : String = ""

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    referenceLabel.text? = specifiedFavorite

    print("The viewDidLoad")
    // SMC LEFT OFF HERE
    // Can't get selectedFavorite to load from previous controller
    print("The Value of variable specifiedFavorite sent from segue is: \(specifiedFavorite)")

    print(specifiedFavorite)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let request = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Passages")

    request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "reference = %@", specifiedFavorite)

    request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    do {

        let results = try context.fetch(request)

        print("fetch request was successful")

        if results.count > 0 {

            for result in results as! [NSManagedObject] {

                //                    print("We got results!")

                if let returnedText = result.value(forKey: "passagetext") as? String {

                    print("This is the value of returnedText: \(returnedText)")

                    passageText.text? = returnedText

                    print("This is the text of the selectedFavorite after segue is: \(passageText)")

                }

            }

        }
    } catch {

        print("Couldn't fetch results")

    }


}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    print("The viewDidLoad")

    print("The Value of variable specifiedFavorite sent from segue is: \(specifiedFavorite)")

    print(specifiedFavorite)
}


}
```

When I run the app, the logs indicate that the value of variable    "specifiedFavorite" is set prior to segue.

```
The variable for selectedFavorite prior to segue is: 
The variable for favoritesDetailsViewController.specifiedFavorite prior to segue is: 
The viewDidLoad
The Value of variable specifiedFavorite sent from segue is: 

The text in the selected cell is John 3:16
The variable for selectedFavorite prior to segue is: John 3:16
The variable for favoritesDetailsViewController.specifiedFavorite prior to segue is: John 3:16
2016-12-10 12:43:54.624 Logos to Mind[4036:770173] <UIView: 0x7ff0bf918010; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x600000421fa0>>'s window is not equal to <Logos_to_Mind.FavoritesDetailsViewController: 0x7ff0bf9047f0>'s view's window!
Segue performed
The FavoritesDetailsViewController viewDidLoad
The Value of variable specifiedFavorite sent from segue is: 
fetch request was successful
```

Note the log message:
The Value of variable specifiedFavorite sent from segue is:

is empty.

This is my problem. I don't see what errors exist in my code that is failing to set that "specifiedFavorite" variable in the FavoritesDetailsViewController. I've hit a brick wall here. Would appreciate some insight.

Comment: Try to add `self`: `favoritesDetailsViewController.specifiedFavorite = self.selectedFavorite`

Comment: As always **do not** get data from a table view cell (the view), get it always from the data source array, (the model) in your case in `didSelectRowAt`: `let favorite = passages[indexPath.row]` `selectedFavorite = favorite.value(forKey: "reference") as! String`

Comment: @shallowThought- That did not work. Also, the value of selectedFavorites is set properly at that point in the code as evidenced in the logs: "The variable for selectedFavorite prior to segue is: John 3:16"

Comment: @vadian - thanks for that tip. I made the change as a recommended best practice, but this does not change the outcome. Still not able to pass the variable.

Comment: The code seems to be correct. According to the code there have to be two printed lines `"The viewDidLoad"` rather than once `The FavoritesDetailsViewController viewDidLoad` like in the log. Is there another *test* class involved?

Comment: Is your segue wired from the prototype cell?  If so, it will be called automatically and **before** `didSelectRowAt`.  In this case, calling `performSegue(withIdentifier:)` will trigger the segue a second time.

Comment: @vacawama - yes, my segue is wired from prototype cell. However, if I comment out the performSegue(withIdentifier:) from the didSelectRowAt I do not get any variables except selectedFavorites variable set in the didSelectRowAt

Comment: @vadian - there are no other test classes. That viewDidLoad comment in the logs belongs to the FavoritesDetailsViewController viewDidLoad. I changed the text to make that more clear. Thx.

Comment: Don't use `didSelectRowAt`.  Do all of your work in `prepareForSegue`.  The `sender` is the `cell` that triggered the segue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your segue is wired from your prototype cell.  Don't bother with `didSelectRowAt` because it is called after `prepare(for:sender)`.  Do all of your work in `prepare(for:sender:)`.  The `sender` is the cell that triggered the segue:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "toFavoritesDetailsViewController" {

        let favoritesDetailsViewController = segue.destination as! FavoritesDetailsViewController

        if let selectedCell = sender as? UITableViewCell {
            let selectedFavorite = (selectedCell.textLabel?.text)!

            favoritesDetailsViewController.specifiedFavorite = selectedFavorite

            print("The variable for selectedFavorite prior to segue is: \(selectedFavorite)")

            print("The variable for favoritesDetailsViewController.specifiedFavorite prior to segue is: \(favoritesDetailsViewController.specifiedFavorite)")
        }

    }
}
```